# How to integrate azure id based login for intune as welll as wrapped app. is it possible to do so or we should have thecredentials entered twice?

Tags: azure, cordova, azure-active-directory, intune

We have wrapped the ios and android apps with intune wrapping tool.  So whenever we login to the app the first page will be a Microsoft login page. Once we enter the credentials there then the actual app login page of the app comes. So can we have the azure id integrated so that there is no need to enter the credentials twice ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to login to Intune you need to have a Azure AD credentials only. As you aware this Intune App Wrapping tool is primarily used for LOB apps and then which allows the app to be managed by an Intune app protection policy.

Generally when we use the App Wrapping Tool, it must ensure that the LOB app is compatible with the desired app protection policies. The ideal method to ensure compatibility would be to integrate the Microsoft Intune App SDK into the LOB app  and this method is best suited to The LOB app has minimal user authentication experiences.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13250275/thirgiftthub-msft-identity - is there a way to get into the application without logging in twice, with only logging in once with the MS login page? How is it supposed to share the token from the MS login to the app?